# How to check if array of strings is sorted

Tags: c++, c++14

How do i check if the given elements in my array of string type are sorted or not. If it were integer type the comparison would've been easy. I can't see how we can do comparison with words.

Comment: What kind of strings? If `std::string` (C++ standard library strings), they can be compared using `<` `>` `==`, just like integers. If C-strings (`NUL`-terminated char arrays), use `strcmp`.

Comment: I'm comparing an of string, say Str[3]={"ali","zedan","kali"}. So, should i compare them using inequality signs?

Comment: how is `Str` defined? Is it `char *Str[3]`? If so, use `strcmp`: `strcmp(s1, s2)` returns negative number, zero, or positive number, if `s1` is less than, equal, or greater than `s2`. It's more like C than C++ if you use this kind of strings. If it's `std::string Str[3]`, regular `<` will work.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` objects can be compared with [the usual operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) just like fundamental types.

You could write the loop by hand or just use the standard library algorithm [`std::is_sorted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted).

```
std::string Str[3] = { "ali", "zedan", "kali" };

bool result = std::is_sorted(Str, Str + 3);

// or using iterators

bool result = std::is_sorted(std::begin(Str), std::end(Str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the appropriate algorithm.

If your "string" type is `std::string`, use the default comparison operator:

```
std::is_sorted(std::begin(my_string_array), std::end(my_string_array);
```

If your "string" type is a C-style string you have to provide a comparison function:

```
std::is_sorted(std::begin(my_string_array), std::end(my_string_array,
    [](const char* lhs, const char* rhs) {
        return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the exact same way. 
Think of a dictionary. The word "apple" would appear in a dictionary before the word "house". This is called Lexicographical Order.

string s1 is smaller than string s2  `s1 < s2` if s1 would appear before s2 in Lexicographical order.

The usual comparison operators apply on strings just as they do on integers

Comment: I'm comparing an of string, say Str[3]={"ali","zedan","kali"}. So, should i compare them using inequality signs?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what you should do

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `std::string`functions, you could compare **characters** just the same as you are comparing **integers**.  Firstly, check the ASCII table below;

[ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/)

As you can see, every character has some corresponding decimal number and they are numbered in an alphabetic order *( a = 97, b = 98, c = 99 ... )* so that you can compare them just the same as integers. **But notice that**, upper and lower case letters have different corresponding decimals. So that, when you will make a comparison in your string to check whether it is sorted or not, first round all of the characters to lower in your string since upper-case letters have more little corresponding decimal numbers than lower-case letters in the ASCII Table. So, your function should be like this;

```
bool is_string_sorted(std::string str){

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; i++){

        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        str[i+1] = tolower(str[i+1]);

        if(str[i] > str[i+1]){

            return false;

        }


    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Interesting note, lowercase differs from upper by only `lower = upper | (1 << 5);` the 6th bit being the lowercase bit for alpha characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- that's true for ASCII, but it is not required by the language definition, and may well not be true for other characters encodings. Use `tolower` and `toupper`.